# How to find the convergence/divergence of the sequence $a_n = \left(2n+3 \over n\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$a_n = \left(2n+3 \over n\right)^n = \left(2 + {3 \over n}\right)^n$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(2 + {3 \over n}\right)^n$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n*ln\left(2 + {3 \over n}\right) $$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {ln\left(2 + {3 \over n}\right) \over {1 \over n}}$$ 
Applying  L'hoptials:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(-3n^{-2} \over -n^{-2} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(3n^{-2} \over n^{-2} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 3 = 3$$

Since I took the natural log in the beginning I need to raise $e$ to the third power.

So the answer should be $e^3$, but my book is saying it's not and that it's divergent to $+\infty$.

Comment: Careful- You can't use L'hopital's rule unless both the numerator and denominator are going to zero. In this case the numerator is approaching ln(2). (There are actually other instances in which l'hopital is valid, but to be safe stick with 0/0).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $2+\frac{3}{n}>2$, so...

Answer (score 0):

$$ \log{\left( 2 + \frac{3}{n} \right)} = \log{2} + \log{\left( 1 + \frac{3}{2n} \right)}, $$
and use the power series for the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = \left(2n+3 \over n\right)^n = \left(2 + {3 \over n}\right)^n=2^n\left(1 + {\frac{3}{2}\over n}\right)^n.$$
The second term tends to $e^{\frac{3}{2}}...$